# Rule is working after deletion in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

superuser!

I have a trouble with lotus notes. I accendentially deleted rule without disabling.
For now rule still working and i unable to delete him or turn off.

How can i delete this rule?

I created some buttons and send it to user. (button clears calendar).
But it didn't work..

thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

Rules are *shadowed* in the "Calendar Profile" in special items. Whenever you create / save / change a rule, it automatically updates the calendar profile.

What happened now is, that the rule has been deleted and the client "forgot" to update the calendar profile, so the rule is still active.

There are several possibilities to get rid of that rule:

The user could first try to create another rule, save it, enable it, disable it, delete it.

As the rule- items in the profile are simply numbered this most probably will overwrite the erroneous item and fix the problem.

You could also completely delete the calendar profile with code.

But take care: A LOT of user preferences are stored there (you can see what is stored there by opening "More - Preferences" from inbox or calendar as this is the calendar profile I am talking about) and will be lost when you go that route.

One important thing about profiles: They are cached in the client. When the user presses a button with your code to delete / update the profile, then he needs to **immediately** close the Notes Client after that without doing anything else. Otherwise it might be, that the client overwrites the changes done with the script with its cached version and you will not see any effect of your script.

Comment: thanks for answer! i deleted calendar profile but nothing happened UNTIL in the evening started COMPACT command(maybe) and then it worked fine!